# mergPopActivity failed to load activities

Tags: livecode

I want users to be able to share an image from my app. I assumed this would be easy using mergPopActivity to display the standard share sheet with the [pimage] parameter pointed to an externally available image.

So I included mergPopActivity in my latest build and was expecting the share sheet to be automatically populated with options available for handling the image. I was surprised to have an "empty" share sheet (Only the "More.." icons showed and they lead to empty lists). If there was an essential step required to get the sheet populated, I would have expected a bunch of forum questions, etc. about mergPopActivity but... there are none.

It makes sense that I would have to let the system know what I want/need access to, especially since the users should be asked for permission but having no information available, I somehow thought it would just work. I found some online tutorials (not Livecode) that show setting up Privacy info in the pList in xCode but I'm not sure what to do with the info since I'm skipping xCode.

Is there a resource that highlights what pList entries/mods are needed to get the various services into the share sheet and available through mergPopActivity?

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator or on a device?

Comment: Testing on iPhone 6, iOS 11.4. Share Sheet in other apps comes up (e.g. notes brings up Message, Mail, Twitter, Facebook with Messenger, Signal & WhatsApp available under More...) Using LC 9.0.0 and testing on device through Develop Menu. Also through Test Flight but...

Comment: OK, is the image inside the app bundle or saved elsewhere (documents folder etc). Also are you listing the full path.

Comment: Monte: I just dropped the image ref and just "shared" text and it worked. Let me chase this a bit more. Will let you know if I had something screwy there.....

Comment: Monte, First part solved. I figured out that I can only have 1 parameter in the merPopActivity command. Problem was stupidity on my part. I somehow thought I could do text and an image in the same instance. I'll do them separately. Also, I was trying to grab an image from specialFolder("documents") but realize the system doesn't have access to that since the path I get is /var/mobile/Conainers/..... Do I have to export to an external server or is there an on-phone location I can use that the system can access? Save to Photo Library?

Comment: can you amend your question with the code you are using. The external reads the image files itself so there should be no issue about access. Also you should be able to include both an image and text.

Comment: Problem solved. Issue was my not understanding exactly how parameters had to be formatted, etc. Found the mergPop demo stack in some old files (from before mergXX was being included in Livecode). Working through that helped... as did remembering to save images using binfile :)